# Selecting 3 random elements from an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, random

I am trying to select three random elements from within a array.
I currently have implemented:

```
result= np.random.uniform(np.min(dataset[:,1]), np.max(dataset[:,1]), size=3
```

Which returns three random floats between the min and max range. I am struggling finding a way to select random elements within an array, instead of a random float which may not exist as an element inside the array.

I have also tried:

```
result = random.choice(dataset[:,0])
```

Which only returns a single element, is it possible to return 3 with this function

Comment: you can also use `np.random.sample(` which has an argument `replace` for with or without replacement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use random.sample(), if you want to sample without replacement, ie. the same element can't be picked twice.

```
>>> import random
>>> l = [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
>>> random.sample(l, 3)
[0.3, 0.5, 0.1]
```

If you want to sample with replacement, you can random.choices()

```
>>> import random
>>> l = [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
>>> random.choices(l, k=3)
[0.3, 0.5, 0.3]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `random.choices` instead:

```
result = random.choices(dataset[:,0], k=3)
```